# Big Graph visualization on a webpage : networkx, vivagraph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph of about 5000 nodes and 5000 links, that i can visualize in Chrome thanks to [the vivagraph javascript library](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS) (webgl is faster than svg - in d3 for example).

My workflow is :

- Building with the [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) python library and output the result as a json file.
- Load the json and construct the graph with [the vivagraph javascript library](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS).
- Nodes positions are computed by the js library

The problem is that it takes time to render the layout with well positionned nodes.

My approach is to pre-compute the nodes position in [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) for example. The really good point on this approach is that it minimize client work on the browser. But i can't achieve good positions on the webpage. I need help on this step.

The relevant python code for the node position computation is :

```
    ## positionning
    try:
        # Position nodes using Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm.
        pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
        for k,v in pos.iteritems():
            # scaling tentative
            # from small float like 0.5555 to higher values
            # casting to int because precision is not important
            pos[k] = [ int(i*1000) for i in v.tolist() ]
    except Exception, e:
        print "positionning failed"
        raise

    ## setting positions
    try:
        # set position of nodes as a node attribute
        # that will be used with the js library
        nx.set_node_attributes(G,'pos', pos)
    except Exception, e:
        print "getting positions failed"
        raise e

    # output all the stuff
    d = json_graph.node_link_data(G)
    with open(args.output,'w') as f:
        json.dump(d,f)
```

Then in my page, in javascript :

```
/*global Viva*/
function graph(file){
  var file = file;

  $.getJSON(file, function(data) {
      var graphGenerator = Viva.Graph.generator();
      graph = Viva.Graph.graph();

      # building the graph with the json data :

      data.nodes.forEach(function(n,i) {
         var node = graph.addNode(n.id,{d: n.d});

         # node position is defined in the json element attribute 'pos'
         node.position = {
             x : n.pos[0],
             y : n.pos[1]
         };
      })

      # adding links between nodes

      data.links.forEach(function(l,i) {
          graph.addLink(data.nodes[l.source].id, data.nodes[l.target].id);
      })


        var max_link = 55
        var min_link = 1

        var colors = d3.scale.linear().domain([min_link,max_link]).range(['#F0F0F0','#252525']);

      var layout = Viva.Graph.Layout.forceDirected(graph, {
         springLength : 80,
         springCoeff : 0.0008,
         dragCoeff : 0.001,
         gravity : -5.0,
         theta : 0.8
      });

      var graphics = Viva.Graph.View.webglGraphics();
      graphics
      .node(function(node){

        # color and size of nodes

        color = colors(node.links.length)
        if(node.id == "root"){
          // pin node on canvas, so no position update
          node.isPinned = true;
          size = 60;
        } else {
          size = 20+(7-node.id.length)*(7-node.id.length);
        }
        return Viva.Graph.View.webglSquare(size,color);
      })
      .link(function(link) {

        # color on links 

        fromId = link.fromId;
        toId = link.toId;
        if(toId == "root" || fromId == "root"){
          return Viva.Graph.View.webglLine("#252525");
        } else {
          if( fromId[0] == toId[0]){
            linkcolor = linkcolors(fromId[0])
            return Viva.Graph.View.webglLine(linkcolor);
          } else {
            linkcolor = averageRGB(linkcolors(fromId[0]),linkcolors(toId[0]))
            return Viva.Graph.View.webglLine('#'+linkcolor);
          }
        }
      }); 

      renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph,
          {
              layout     : layout,
              graphics   : graphics,
              enableBlending: false,
              renderLinks : true,
              prerender  : true
          });

      renderer.run();
  });
}
```

I am now trying [Gephi](https://gephi.org), but i don't want to use the [gephi toolkit](https://gephi.org/toolkit/) as i am not used to java.

If somebody got some hints on this, please avoid me hundred of trials and maybe failure ;)

Comment: Hi, have you found anything useful for your question?

Comment: Hi, in fact i switched to another kind of solution : i use d3.js to display a static graph in svg, then i save the (big) svg and render it in png with a big resolution. Then i get tiles of it with gda2tiles.py and use leafletJS to display it ala google maps !

Comment: Wow that's a lot of work! Thanks for the sharing mate :)

Comment: You might want to try the seadragon Gephi plugin... it's pretty easy to export, and pretty scalable. Another idea would be to export to gexf (it should preserve positions), and render it using sigma.js

Comment: That sounds useful enough that it would be great as a little library.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Layout assumes that the edge weights uphold the metric property, i.e Weight(A,B)+Weight(A,C) > Weight(B,C). If this is not the case, then networkx tries to place them as realistic as possible.

You could try to adjust this by

```
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G,k=\alpha, iterations=\beta)
    # where 0.0<\alpha<1.0 and \beta>0 
    # k is the minimum distance between the nodes
    # iterations specify the simulated annealing runs
    # This code works only on Networkx 1.8 and not earlier versions
```